# How to use GIT within webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Folks,

We are a team coding in Angular and nodejs.

Our code sits on a Linux server. This is where each one of us checks-in and checks-out code from our central git repo. This worked fine until I was using vi.

Now we are using Webstorm which is installed on my Win machine. From webstorm I FTP into my git repo on linux machine. So how do I automate this whole Webstorm from Windows to **Linux** git repo work ?

Any clues ?

Answer (score 3):

Refer the jetbrains webstorm help page,how to use Git integration:

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/using-git-integration.html

Install git plugin if you dont have:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3033?pr=

Answer (score 1):

Use Webstorm's Git [plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/using-git-integration.html) to grab a clone of the Git repo on your Linux machine and bring it down to your local Windows machine. After that, you use the plugin from the VCS menu or right-clicking the file in WebStorm to commit, push, etc. Of course you can also use the plugin to create branches, perform merges, and all the other Git stuff.

The Linux/Windows thing will be transparent to you.